# Pandas replace specific cells with corresponding values from another series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following pd.DataFrame:

| INDEX | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| C | 9 | 6 | 3 |

And also the following pd.Series:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | -4 | -5 |

I would like to replace the values is the DataFrame that are bigger than, or equal to 6, with the respective values from the Series, according to the column name.
For example, I would like to replace cell `Ab` (7>6), with -4 (since cell `Ab` is in col `b`, and the series had -4 in that index).
In the above example, the DataFrame will look like:

| ~ | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | -4 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| C | -1 | -4 | 3 |

I know how to identify the required cells using:
`df[df>=6]`, but when I'm trying to assign the series (`df[df>=6]=series`) I get an error.

Thanks  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `mask` and `fillna`:

```
out = df.mask(df.ge(6)).fillna(s, downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
       a  b  c
INDEX         
A      5 -4  2
B      3  2  1
C     -1 -4  3
```

Comment: Is it correct that in this solution series index should match those of df column names?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR yes, this is the principle of index alignment ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions. You are an inspiration to me.

Comment: You're welcome @Anoushiravan thank you for your heartwarming comment and happy coding ;)

Answer (score 3):

Lets do `mask` along `axis=1`

```
df.mask(df >= 6, series, axis=1)
```

---

```
       a  b  c
INDEX         
A      5 -4  2
B      3  2  1
C     -1 -4  3
```

Answer (score 1):

With boolean indexing and `fillna`:

```
s = pd.Series([-1,-4,-5],['a','b','c'])
df[df.lt(6)].fillna(s)
```

---

```
         a    b  c
INDEX             
A      5.0 -4.0  2
B      3.0  2.0  1
C     -1.0 -4.0  3
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)